Is there a sometimes adjust in the paralist package?
I have in my preamble \usepackage[neverdecrease,flushleft,neveradjust]{paralist} because on some types of lists I want to never adjust margins.  However, I would like to adjust margins. Is there a way to make the neveradjust option local or apply only to certain newlist environments?

Maybe switch to the somewhat newer and probably more flexible enumitem package?

Always provide a small but complete example that can be used to test solutions.
